# The padding of buttons with the help of anchor tag does not seem to be of the same width because of the content inside

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I was trying to create a few buttons with the help of the anchor tag. I have set the padding of each of these tags to get the button look. However, due to the content inside the buttons does not seem to be of the same size even after I had added the box-sizing property.

HTML

```
<ul>
<li class="list-pad"><a class="link-bg" href="{{link}}">{{location}}</a> </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.link-bg
{
    width:2em;
    padding: 0.417em 0.833em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    background-color: #007AFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For them to be of same size, you must change the `display` properties of anchor tag.

```css
.link-bg
{
    width:2em;
    padding: 0.417em 0.833em;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    background-color: #007AFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="list-pad"><a class="link-bg" href="#">{{location}}</a> </li>
  <li class="list-pad"><a class="link-bg" href="#">{{location.location}}</a> </li>
</ul>
```